# Add the same UIView in another UIView multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uikit

Is it possible to add the same view multiple times to another view.   I'm trying to do this with `addSubview`, but the end result is the view I've added is only at the last position that was set.

```
while (count <= [_testItemArray count]) {
    [self.parentView addSubview:self.childrenView];
    yPosition = count * 37;
    [self.childrenView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosition, 0, 0)];
    count++;
}
```

The app I am building retrieves the information that goes in the `childrenView` at runtime.  The number of `childrenView` could vary each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only add an instance of a `UIView` once, but if you subclass `UIView` and create a class for your custom view, you can instantiate it as many times as you like.

My suggestion is to make a class `MyCustomView` that is a subclass of `UIView`. Then your loop will look like this:

```
while (count <= [_testItemArray count]) {
    MyCustomView *customView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
    [self.parentView addSubview:customView;
    [customView release];
    yPosition = count * 37;
    [customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosition, 0, 0)];
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I just edited my Question to reflect that I also see the childrenView's frame.  Would the code segment that you posted change to [self.customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPosition, 0, 0)]; ?